# Extending view to generate PDF returns error after upgrade to Rails 6.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

Until recently I extended the Rails view to generate a PDF in a service object:

```
view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})
view.extend(ApplicationHelper)
view.extend(Rails.application.routes.url_helpers)

WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
  view.render(
    pdf: pdf_title,
    template: template,
    locals: { timesheet: timesheet },
    print_media_type:  true,
    orientation:       'Portrait',
    page_size:         'A4'
  )
)
```

After upgrading to Rails 6.1, this gives an error, because there has been a change in this line:

```
view = ActionView::Base.new(ActionController::Base.view_paths, {})
```

There is now a 3rd parameter `controller` mandatory according to this commit in the Rails source.
This:

```
def initialize(lookup_context, assigns = {}, controller = nil)
```

Changed to this:

```
def initialize(lookup_context, assigns, controller)
```

But I am not sure what `controller` is in this case and what I should provide as 3rd parameter, as this is all called from a service object an not a controller. Also just adding a `nil` value as 3rd parameter is not working, because then the PDF is unreadable when opened, so I guess it doesn't extend the view properly.

So any idea what value to provide as 3rd parameter?

Comment: If you had a controller, I would think calling `TimesheetsController.renderer.render(template:'timesheets/show)` would give you the html, but if there's no controller, would simply calling `ApplicationController.renderer.render` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use one of your base controller to render, instead of the view, you may be able to get the html you need. Using a controller that already has the route and view helpers in it will also alleviate the need to manually extends/include them.

```
WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
  ApplicationController.renderer.render(
    pdf: pdf_title,
    template: template,
    locals: { timesheet: timesheet },
    print_media_type:  true,
    orientation:       'Portrait',
    page_size:         'A4'
  )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this indeed works and no need anymore to explicitly extend the views